# Structured arrays: Do operations on views result in scattered arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, structured-array

I have a numpy structured array `a` and create a view `b` on it:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(3, dtype={'names':['A','B','C'], 'formats':['int','int','float']})
b = a[['A', 'C']]
```

The `descr` component of the data type of `b` indicates that the data are stored somehow "scattered".

```
>>> b.dtype.descr
[('A', '<i4'), ('', '|V4'), ('C', '<f8')]
```

(After reading the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#indexing-structured-arrays) I believe that the component `('', '|V4')` indicates a "gap" in the data, as `b` is just a view on `a`. )

If this bothers me, I can copy the data:

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf
c = rf.repack_fields(b)
```

and

```
>>> c.dtype.descr
[('A', '<i4'), ('C', '<f8')]
```

as desired.

This step requires me to copy the data. Now sometimes, I would like to apply an operation to the view. Often, these operations would return a copy of the array anyways. For example,

```
d = np.concatenate((b,b))
```

returns a copy of the data in `b` and `a`. Nonetheless,

```
>>> d.dtype.descr
[('A', '<i4'), ('', '|V4'), ('C', '<f8')]
```

indicates that the data are not stored efficiently.

**So is there a way to work with views without producing "scattered" results? Would I always have to create a copy beforehand? Or is there no efficiency issue but only a weird way how `descr` describes the data type? (If so, how can I avoid that?)**

This question becomes particularly relevent, if I want to neglect intermediate steps:

```
d = np.concatenate((a[['A', 'C']], a[['A', 'C']]))
```

I am working with numpy 1.16 and python 3.7.

Answer (score 2):

Multifield indexing has been in a state of flux for sometime now.  With `1.16` they seemed to have settled on this 'offset' form of 'views', requiring an explicit repacking if you want a 'clean' copy.

```
In [231]: np.__version__                                                             
Out[231]: '1.16.1'
In [232]: a.dtype                                                                    
Out[232]: dtype([('A', '<i8'), ('B', '<i8'), ('C', '<f8')])
In [233]: a[['A','C']].dtype                                                         
Out[233]: dtype({'names':['A','C'], 'formats':['<i8','<f8'], 'offsets':[0,16], 'itemsize':24})
```

In this view, the values for 'B' are still present (at offset 8).  Think of the databuffer as having:

```
[a0, b0, c0, a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, ....]
```

The [233] 'view' looks at the same databuffer, but only gives us access to the `A` and `C` fields.  `repack_fields` creates a new databuffer with:

```
[a0, c0, a1, c1, ....]
```

If `a` had been a regular `(n,3)` array, `a[:, [0,2]]` would be a copy.  We could not skip `a[:,1]` and still have a view.

```
In [234]: np.concatenate((a[['A','C']],a[['A','C']]))                                
Out[234]: 
array([(0, 0.), (1, 1.), (2, 2.), (0, 0.), (1, 1.), (2, 2.)],
      dtype={'names':['A','C'], 'formats':['<i8','<f8'], 'offsets':[0,16], 'itemsize':24})
```

Playing around with `view` I find that the field at offset 8 (the 'B' field in `a`) still exists, but is uninitialized (as in a `np.empty` array).

Different ways of displaying this 'scattered' dtype:

```
In [238]: a1.dtype                                                                   
Out[238]: dtype({'names':['A','C'], 'formats':['<i8','<f8'], 'offsets':[0,16], 'itemsize':24})

In [239]: a1.dtype.descr                                                             
Out[239]: [('A', '<i8'), ('', '|V8'), ('C', '<f8')]

In [241]: a1.dtype.fields                                                            
Out[241]: mappingproxy({'A': (dtype('int64'), 0), 'C': (dtype('float64'), 16)})
```

I can reorder the fields as well:

```
In [248]: a[['B','C','A']].dtype                                                     
Out[248]: dtype({'names':['B','C','A'], 'formats':['<i8','<f8','<i8'], 'offsets':[8,16,0], 'itemsize':24})
In [249]: a[['B','C','A']].dtype.descr                                               
...
ValueError: dtype.descr is not defined for types with overlapping or out-of-order fields
```

Comment: Thanks, you are describing well what I have sloppily called "scattered data", and you show nocely that the issue actually exist (which was one of my questions). Do you also have an idea how I could avoid ending up with such a "scattered data type" (without copying everything again)? If there is no builtin way to do that, this is an answer as well. Then I would be interested in the most elegant workaround.

Comment: The whole point with the 1.16 changes is that multifield indexing produces a view, not a copy.  The repack function is provided if you want the older copy behavior. The field copy that you did in the other question utilizes the new view behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For **concatenate only**, you can simply do:

```
a     = np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)], 'f,f,f')
view  = a[['f0','f2']]

b     = np.empty(4, 'f,f')
b[:2] = view
b[2:] = view

print(b)
```

output:

```
array([(1., 3.), (4., 6.), (1., 3.), (4., 6.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
```

EDIT: Forget about what I said about `np.add`, it isn't supposed to work anyway

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would indeed be interested in a more general answer, though. I am aware that I can build workarounds. I just thought that the numpy developers have thought of this problem and introduced a nice way to deal with it...